# Cannot add new Scaffold Item in MVC project VS2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a project which has 2 parts the solution, DAL and Website
I am trying to generate a controller from a model in the DAL, but the DAL models are not showing up in the Model Class entry field in the create scaffold item dialog

Things Ive tried:
rebuilt the entire solution
deleted the folder and restored from repo
opened the solution in an older version of VS

nothing seems to work. The view models show up fine in the dialog, but the domain models from teh external DAL are not showing at all

Comment: Are you using same .NET framework for DAL and MVC projects? One reason for such behavior could be due to .NET framework mismatch in source & target projects.

Comment: That hadn't occurred to me, but both projects reference .net 4.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seem that you don't have the reference in your MVC project to your DAL project, have you tried this already ?

[image: Right Button]

[image: Select the DAL project]

Comment: Reference is not the issue. All other aspects of DAL and WEbsite work perfectly. Only fails when I try and create scaffold controller

Comment: I stand corrected. I wasnt referencing the DAL as you did in the screenshot above. I had my reference pointing directly to the DLL being produced by the DAL project